# Azure Storage PHP client fails to authenticate when uploading streamed file content

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage-files

I'm using the [azure-storage-php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php) library to copy files to an Azure Storage Fileshare.

Moving files to the fileshare works in general, but when using streamed file content, I get an authentication error:

```
Fail:
Code: 403
Value: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
details (if any): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:070c24e7-ABCD-EFGH-7f8e6d000000
Time:2019-10-10T11:45:35.8832342Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'X+WJOUaKHhOABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZe5Iu2k=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


568340

text/csv
Thu, 10 Oct 2019 11:45:35 GMT





x-ms-range:bytes=0-568339
x-ms-request-id:5d9f19dfd2dae
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
x-ms-write:Update
/username/file-share-name/myFile.csv
comp:range'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

I've already made sure that system time is in sync, as some people had issues with this.

The file even is created on the storage and filled with lots of lines of

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I'm using https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem as an abstraction layer.
To open the stream I both tried using `$stream = fopen('filePath.csv', 'rb')` and `$flysystem->readStream('localFilesystem', 'filePath.csv');`

Comment: One thing you would want to check is the size of the stream you're uploading.

Comment: @GauravMantri Having a look at the file size was a very good hint. Turns out that the streamed file (in my case) needs to be around 4MB or larger to not get this error. 
Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: I have no idea :). I just saw the error details and inferred that stream size could be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hint from Gaurav Mantri I figured that the error only occurs when the size of the streamed file is below a certain threshold. In my case this was about 4MB.

Uploading streamed files < 4MB resulted in the described error.

Uploading streamed files > 4MB works just fine.

Unfortunately I don't have an explanation why this happens. 
I now use a workaround to check the file size before uploading it and then either use a direct upload or use a stream for larger files.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Storage PHP client libraries will be retired on 17 March 2024, so try to use Azure Storage REST API. Refer the below microsoft link for more details,

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/retirement-notice-the-azure-storage-php-client-libraries-will-be-retired-on-17-march-2024/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34829280)